# Populating an excel table

Tags: excel

Folks,

I am having problems with populating a table in Excel, and it is as follows:

Lets suppose there are -for example- two tables:

1) Table A

2) Table B

Both tables are made of 3 columns and 6 rows each; however, every cell of table A is made of a single row and in case of table B the cell is made of two rows.

Question:

How can I pull the data from table A and fill table B with it? I have tried all I know but without any success!

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Thanks in advanced

Héctor

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried. What code isn't working? Are we talking a worksheet-function or VBA?

Comment: What do you mean by "every cell of Table B is made of two rows? Have you merged them?

Comment: It would be super helpful to get a screenshot, or some example data to help out with this one.

Comment: Dear @LanceRoberts, It is a worksheet-function what I am looking for. Table B is made of two rows because they are merged by default (it is a template I cannot modify). A screenshot of what I have can be found by clicking on the following link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdcwckz6mk3qeka/Screenshot%202015-06-18%2021.19.08.png?dl=0

Thank you very much guys for your kindness!

Answer (score 0):

In the cell in Table B put a simple assignment formula in the first cell to pull the value from Table A. So using your linked example, in G19 put the formula

```
=C19
```

Your formatting there should already be setup to place the value in the bottom position.

Comment: thank you for your help. Unfortunately I have tried that trick and there is not success. Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: @Hector, well if you don't give more details, you're going to have a hard time finding an answer. This isn't a website of psychics. You need to be very specific on what your problem is and what you've tried and what isn't working.